# How do I call a Sub?

Tags: vb.net

I am teaching myself VB and am trying to call the sub `Main()` however, when I include it after the `End Sub` it says Syntax error and when I run it without calling, nothing happens. Please could you explain to me what I am doing wrong and how to call the sub.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Sub Main()
        HouseCalc(99800, 43100)
        Call HouseCalc(380950, 49500)
    End Sub

    Sub HouseCalc(price As Single, wage As Single)
        If 2.5 * wage <= 0.8 * price Then
            MsgBox("You cannot afford this house.")
        Else
            MsgBox("This house is affordable.")
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Thanks,
Marcus

Comment: The Main() entrypoint of a VB.NET program must be declared *Shared*.  Not using a project template is getting you into trouble.

Comment: @marcus .. use another Sub name .. not Main() ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only put executable code, such as sub or function calls, inside a sub or a function; not directly within a class.

However, your `Sub Main()` is never being called; the `Sub Main()` that VB calls when starting your program must be in a `Module`.
(and your project already has one; look at Properties/My Project)

Comment: hi, sorry for not understanding, I am new to this, how would I create a module or how would I find the one that my project already has, I have looked in Properties/My Project and could not find it. Thanks, Marcus

Comment: @marcus: Right-click the project, Add New Item, Module.  Look in My Project Properties for the startup settings.